# Pentaho Kettle Naming Reason

Tags: pentaho, kettle, data-integration

why the pentaho kettle is being called as "Pentaho Data Integration" tool?
can we able to use multiple data sources in a single transformation?

Answer (score 3):

The name evolved from "KDE ETTL Environment" to "Kettle ETTL Environment" after the plan of developing the software on top of KDE (K Desktop Environment) was dropped. After several years of development (started on 2000), Pentaho acquired the rights to the source code and employed [Matt Casters](http://www.ibridge.be/?page_id=2) ,the father of Kettle as lead developer of Kettle. The name "Pentaho Data Integration" was a late re-branding.

You can find the full story on [Pentaho Kettle Solutions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470635177)

---

Yes, you can use multiple data sources in the same transformation. However keep in mind that a *transformation* is a data flow process which consists of one or more *steps* connected by *hops*. That means that in order to build a stream of records from different data sources you'll have to define a step that performs the action required (such as pulling data using a query) for each of the data sources that you need.

Comment: ...and now became hitachi vantara after another acquisition and one more re-branding.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You'll be able to use multiple data sources in a single transformation.

Pentaho Data Integration is an ETL (Extract Transform Load) tool. Like many other ETL tools PDI supports multiple data sources. Please refer [http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Freport_designer_user_guide%2Fconcept_supported_datasources.html](http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/report_designer_user_guide/concept_supported_datasources.html)

Answer (score 0):

1) Initially it was called as KETTLE and later on only it was renamed to PDI or Pentaho data integration as it was acquired by PENTAHO. Now recently this PENTAHO is acquired by Hitachi, Data systems company. Now this Hitachi became the parent organisation.

2)  Now coming to data sources. Yes, obviously we can use multiple data sources in a single transformation. eg) Table input, Excel input, salesforce input, text file input, fixed file input, Microsoft access, RSS, XML and many more available as input data sources in PDI.